# PyQt4 QHBoxLayout cell size issue

Tags: layout, pyqt4

I am using PyQt4 QHBoxLayout to creat a window with multiply frame, here is my part of my code

```
    def initUI(self):      

    hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

    topleft = QtGui.QFrame(self)
    topleft.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)

    topright = QtGui.QFrame(self)
    topright.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)

    bottom = QtGui.QFrame(self)
    bottom.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)

    splitter1 = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    splitter1.addWidget(topleft)
    splitter1.addWidget(topright)

    splitter2 = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
    splitter2.addWidget(splitter1)
    splitter2.addWidget(bottom)

    hbox.addWidget(splitter2)
    self.setLayout(hbox)

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
    self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QSplitter')
    self.show()
```

but the output seems wired, because the toplift and topright frame are squeezed, I am wondering if there is any to solve this problem to make the height of toplift and topright is the same as the height of bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Qt Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html#setSizes), `QSplitter` has a `setSize` method:

> `void QSplitter::setSizes(const QList<int> & list)`
>
> Sets the child widgets respective sizes to the values given in the
>   list.
>
> If the splitter is horizontal, the values set the widths of each
>   widget in pixels, from left to right. If the splitter is vertical, the
>   heights of each widget is set, from top to bottom.
>   ...

Also, for any `QWidget`, you can use `setMinimumSize`.